# Default exchange calendar on iPhone (Google Sync)

Tags: iphone, calendar, exchange-activesync, google-sync

I am using Google Sync to connected various calendars between my Google account and my iPhone. Some of these calendars are subscribed to calendars (national holidays/sporting events etc). When I go to create a new calendar entry on my iPhone it always selects the national holidays calendar, rather than my own, is there a way of setting my own calendar to be the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the calendar settings inside the settings app (Mai, Contacts, Calendars) at the bottom of that menu there is an option to set the Default Calendar. I'm thinking it's set to National Holidays at the moment so you can just change it there so all new entries should reside in the default calendar.

Hope that helps!

Comment: or maybe the issue is within google calendars...

Comment: Thanks, I thought the "Import From Sim" button was the very bottom of that page. Doh!